# Retrieving jQuery.data() values from within setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. I'm using jQuery's .data() method to store state in a plugin I'm writing. Everything works fine, except for when I try to retrieve these data values from within a setInterval block. I am able to see the jQuery object inside the setInterval block, but I'm not able to see values stored by the data() method.

```
tminusStart: function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var $tminus = $(this).data("tminus.state", "running");

    var intervalId = setInterval(function(tm) {
      if ($tminus.tminusIsRunning()) {
        $tminus.tminusDecrementCounter();

        $tminus.data("tminus.settings").tick_event();

        if ($tminus.tminusTimeRemaining() <= 0) {
          $tminus.data("tminus.settings").expiration_event();
        }

        $tminus.text(tminus.tminusTimeRemaining);
      }
      else {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }, 1000, $tminus);
  });
}
```

In the above code, the $tminus does return the jQuery object alright, but the calls to the functions - which are calling the .data() method - return undefined; so does the .data("tminus.settings") call.

Any help in understanding why .data() isn't working here would be greatly appreciated.

Rewrite of function removing cruft:

```
tminusStart: function() {
  var tminus = this;
  tminus.data("tminus.state", "running");

  return this.each(function() {
    console.log(tminus.data("tminus.state")); // "running"
    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
      console.log(tminus.data("tminus.state")); // undefined
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

I need to know why it's undefined in the setInterval block

Comment: Which is the version of jQuery used?

Comment: When exactly are you assigning a value to `$tminus.data("tminus.settings")`?

Comment: @Frederic I'm assigning it elsewhaere in the plugin. The problem just seems to be that the previously set data() values are not retrievable within the setInterval block.

Answer (score 0):

What are `tminusIsRunning` and `tminusDecrementCounter`?  Did you mean to call that under `$tminus`? Unless you're extending jQuery, those calls are going to error out.  If you're using Chrome, check the Javascript Console, you should see something like: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tminusIsRunning'"

Comment: Whoops, no, I've been messing with the code so much, I've just left some things out in my haste to copy stuff over to SO. I'll fix that shortly.

Comment: The tminusIsRunning() and tminusDecrementCounter are wrappers which access the data("tminus.status") and data("tminus.time_remaining") values. Alluded to it in the original post, but probably wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

.data() doesn't work with xhtml + IE (see [note in docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/#jQuery-data1)).

Alternatively, This looks like a jQ extension, so watch out for that. jQuery has a (IMO) bad habit of aliasing `this` all over the place. Make sure you don't have a dependency on `this` being something different than what it is. I suggest installing firebug and using `console.log` to log `this` in both the place where you set the value, and where you access it. If it's not the IE issue, I suspect this would locate it.

Comment: Not using IE. I'm aware of the issues with "this" and I've been debugging using console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. I'm using jasmine to test drive this and the jasmine-jquery library has a fixtures piece which I'm apparently not using correctly. I tested the code in a webpage and everything is now working according to plan. Now I just have to make sure all my tests are passing.

I won't accept my own answer since I didn't provide the necessary information to begin with. I appreciate everyone's time on this. I really wish I could have accepted someone's answer.